# How to combine factor levels when using group_by in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on a data frame that has a column of three levels, and I'd like to group_by and summarise. If I just want selected levels and combine others to an "other" level, is there a way to do it in the group_by() instead of combining these levels at the beginning?

Comment: you might want to consider a mutate(grouping_new_column = case_when(grouping_old_column = 'group_D' ~"Other")) kind of statement. This would look something like: "dplyr::select(ColumnA, columnB) %>% dplyr::mutate(grouping_new_column = case_when(grouping_old_column = "group_D" ~"Other)) %>% group_by(grouping_new_column) %>% summarize(....) I know this isn't a super thorough answer. Would help if you could include a reproducible example

Comment: You can also look into `forcats::fct_lump`.